# Bash + remove spaces from line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I wrote the following bash code in order to create CSV path with disks partitions , so each partition will get new increment dev disk

```
number_of_disks=5
mount_p=({a..z})
path=` for i in \`seq 1 $number_of_disks \`; do mount_p="$(echo $mount_p| tr '[a-z]' '[b-z]a')"; echo /home/sd$mount_p/oop/app/data","; done `
```

but when I print the $path we get space between each partion

```
echo $path
/home/sdb/oop/app/data, /home/sdc/oop/app/data, 
/home/sdd/oop/app/data, /home/sde/oop/app/data, 
/home/sdf/oop/app/data,
```

Second problem is the unnecessary "," at the end of the line

Based on my code how to create the path variable without space and without "," at the end of the CSV line

Comment: Why do you combine `$(cmd)` with `\`cmd\``? Just use `$(cmd)`. You won't need any backslashes and your code will look better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a very complex way (hacky as hell) to achieve something rather simple:

```
path=$(echo /home/sd{a..e}/oop/app/data | tr ' ' ,)
```

Comment: what in case we need it flexible , in your example its based on  only "5" disks but we want the "e" as variable , as sd{a..$var}    , in my code I wrote seq 1 5 , so if I want to change the number of disks the I will replace the 5 number with $var

Comment: `x=q; path=$(eval echo /home/sd{a..$x}/oop/app/data | tr ' ' ,)`  But be wary when using `eval`.  If you don't really know the input (because it came from somewhere not under your complete influence), it can be a security breach.

Comment: ok , but I prefer to run it in loop ( or other solution ) that count the number of disks as 1 seq 5 ( in case of 5 disks ) , in your case I need  to translate the q from number of disks    , see my update

Comment: Don't change your question ;-)  But I think you could convert your number into the character easily, e. g. using `n=8; c=$(dc <<< "$n 96 + P"); path=$(eval echo /home/sd{a..$c}/oop/app/data | tr ' ' ,)`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your path variable like tihs:

```
echo $path | sed 's/ //g;s/,$//g'
```

It will remove last `','` and spaces.

UPD.
Or:

```
path=( $(echo /home/sd{b..z}/oop/app/data | tr ' ' ',') ); echo "${path[@]}"
```

Comment: `path=( $(echo /home/sd{b..z}/oop/app/data | tr ' ' ',') ); echo "${path[@]}"`